# Regex : Dot.test() always return true, why?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why it (dot) always return true?

```
var regExp = new RegExp('.', 'i');
alert(regExp.test('edee'))
```

Please check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/utLdwn5a/

Comment: `.` in regex represents any character..so it will always return `true`

Comment: `.` matches any single character. TO match `.` literal use `'\.'`. To match exactly one character, use anchors. `^.$`. Also, no need of `i` flag. I'll also suggest to use **regex literal syntax**.

Comment: Do we have any way to work it as usual?

Comment: can you define `as usual`??if you want to include `.` then you have to escape it as `\.`

Comment: '.' finds a single character.! so it should always return true.!

Comment: Why it was down voted, please?

Comment: This is the most basic question of `regex`..you should have googled it before asking..

PS: I am not the downvoter

Comment: @rock321987 I googled it first, didn't find any solution, and then I reached it to here..Is this place not to get resolution of your problems?? Show me a googled link if you have for this..

Comment: @himanshupareek66 you will not get cooked answer to the question as you wish..see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

you will find the meaning of metacharcter..`.` is the basic metacharcter in `regex`..you could have easily understood it..

Comment: @himanshupareek66 and I was just telling what downvoter might have thought the reason for downvoting..the downvoter might have thought that question is `not well researched`

Comment: @rock321987, got it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot in regex matches any character. Escape it like this:

```
var regExp = new RegExp('\\.', 'i');
alert(regExp.test('edee'))//False
alert(regExp.test('e.dee')) //True
```

Comment: But if there are two Dots in expression, like 
var regExp = new RegExp('\\..', 'i');
alert(regExp.test('ee.t'))
Then it work wrong..

Comment: You have to escape each dot, so if you were to match for "e..dee" you need this: var regExp = new RegExp('\\.\\.', 'i');